# How to find out if a key exists in a hash, then use that information ruby

Tags: ruby

I have read the lines of  a text file into a hash of chars.  Now I need to make it so only the alphabetical chars appear, not the special chars and punctuation.   I have tried this:

```
File.open(WORKING_DIR + '/code.txt','r') do |f|
   char_count = Hash.new(0) # create a hash where 0 is the default value
   f.each_char do |c| # iterate on each character

              char_count.has_key?(c)
              char_count[c] +=1

   end
end

puts char_count.inspect
```

But when I inspect my hash, all punctuation is still present.  How am I using has_key incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure you want to merely collect the alpha-chars into a hash? Check your requirements - maybe you should be just removing the non-alpha chars from your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely seem to be missing some things here.  Since you've tagged this as homework, I'm not going to give you an outright solution, but here's some things to look into:

First, [each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-each_char) iterates through every single character -- not just alphanumerics:

```
irb(main):001:0> "xyz.abc".each_char { |c| print c, ' ' }
x y z . a b c => "xyz.abc"
```

So, you will need some sort of test for that.

Second, inside your iterator, you're not actually applying your `has_key?` test -- you will need to use some logic here to decide when to increment your hash.

Comment: @mrwienerdog It's baffling to me how this answer can be accepted without even a comment. I think it's a helpful answer, but no one else can see *how* it was helpful.